# Evaluate $\iiint_V zdV$, V is volume bounded below by cone $x^2+y^2 = z^2$ and above by sphere$ x^2+y^2+z^2=1$,lying on positive side of y-axis.

Tags: calculus, integration

$\iiint_V zdV = \iiint_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} zdzdydx = \iint_D \frac{1-2(x^2+y^2)}{2}dxdy$ where D is given by the disc $x^2+y^2 = \frac{1}{2}$

Changing x,y into cylindrical coordinates, $x = rcos\theta\;; y = rsin\theta$

Limits of r : $0 \;to\;\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ Given by the intersection of the two surfaces.
Limits of $\theta\;: 0\;to\;\pi$. As only positive side of y-axis is considered.
Is my parametrization correct. Iam having problem in converting into spherical coordinates.I will be glad if someone can show me how. Thank You.

Comment: In your solution we should have $z=\pm \sqrt{{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}}\,\,,\,\,\,z=\pm \sqrt{1-{{x}^{2}}-{{y}^{2}}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
  & x=\rho \cos \theta \sin \phi  \\ 
 & y=\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi  \\ 
 & z=\rho \cos \phi  \\ 
\end{align}
$$\left| \frac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (\rho ,\theta ,\phi )} \right|={{\rho }^{2}}\sin \phi  $$

$${{z}^{2}}={{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,{{\rho }^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\phi ={{\rho }^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\phi \xrightarrow{0\le \phi \le \pi }\,\,\phi =\frac{\pi }{4}\,\,,\,\frac{3\pi }{4}$$ 
$${{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}\,+{{z}^{2}}\,=1\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\rho =1$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi }{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{4}}{\int_{0}^{1}{{{\rho }^{3}}\sin 2\phi \,d\phi d\rho d\theta }}}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi }{\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\pi}{\int_{0}^{1}{{{\rho }^{3}}\sin 2\phi \,d\phi d\rho d\theta }}}$$
[image]

Comment: Hi why the limits pi/4 to 3pi/4. Also the integral sin2phi would be cos2phi and with those limits, the value would be zero

Comment: Hi Rohita note $$\underbrace{{{\rho }^{2}}\sin \phi }_{J}\,\underbrace{\rho \cos \phi }_{Z}=\frac{1}{2}{{\rho }^{3}}\sin 2\phi $$

Comment: Yes that is fine. What iam asking isif we integrate the sin func it gives cos and given the limits it gives cos 3pi/2 - cospi/2 both of which are zero hence the value is zero? Please check

Comment: Sorry It was edited.

Comment: Hi Iam having difficulty in arriving at the limits of phi?.please explain. Without the plot, how to say we should integrate from 0 to pi/4 and 3pi/4 to pi

Comment: Even the sum of the two integrals above is zero

Comment: The region of Integration is symmetric about all three axes and the function $f(z)=z$ is an odd function in the variable $z$ , so the value of the integral is $0$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral

Comment: Check example 2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral

Comment: One last que : How to get that limits of phi under which we have to integrate i.e from 0 to pi/4 and 3pi/4 to pi

Comment: $x=0\implies  z=+y , z=-y$